# SharePoint Online - User experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, classic-experience, modern-document-library

I have a question with regards to "User experience" settings in SharePoint. When I grant access to user for a specific library or folder, he can access that library or folder but the user experience turns to the old classic experience, and if I try to exit from this view, I cannot do that.

Instead, I have to give this user a permission on the site level so after he enters this library or folder, he can view this with the new experience.

This happen to me for some sites that I manage in our company.

Comment: can you attach supporting screen shot?

Comment: @RajatSahani it's been attached

Comment: Not able to produce issue. it is working fine at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, after setting access permissions at the Document library level or Folder level. When that user accesses the Document library or Folder it does not limit the user experience to classic mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

1.Click "**Exit classic experience**" to see if it will switch to modern mode.

[image]

2.Test with other Document library

3.Clear the browser cache or use another browser.

Comment: I checked clicking on "Exit Classic experience" - it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings >> Site collection features.

Click on deactivate button  to “**Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**”

[image]
#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/06/limited-access-user-permission-lockdown-mode-feature.html#ixzz8DfscIxrl